# What are sources that say l'chatchila one can daven shachrit until chatzos?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla, zemanim

What are sources (in the poskim) that say **l'chatchila** one can daven shachrit until chatzos? (if there are)

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there are any?

Comment: Is "(in the poskim)" meant to exclude sources in the Talmud?

Comment: @Alex yes not in talmud

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59137/170

Comment: Yosef, it seems there's some confusion what you mean. Please [edit] to explicitly state the case of your question and what you want to know about it.

Comment: @yoseflavi I think the issue is that we're not sure what you mean by "l'chatchila"; even with bolding the word we're still not sure what type of situation you're referring to.

Comment: IMO it is worth putting this on hold as unclear pending further edits, cc @Alex

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed.

Comment: In the source of the malchokes itself between the chachamim and rebbi yehudah. We oaskon like rebbi yehudah who says tefillah is up to 4 hours and the chachamim who say until chatzos

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge I am not aware of any source L'chatchila. Here is the source for B'Dieved.

[Orach Chaim 89:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=233) says that if one missed Davening Shacharis within the first four hours of the day they can B'Dieved Daven until Chatzos. Mishna Berura explains that this may be done even if it was intentional.

However one who Davens after the first four hours one should not say the Brachos of Kriyas Shema (Yotzer Or, Ahava Raba, Go'al Yisrael) [Orach Chaim 58:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=178&hilite=)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by *l'chatchila*. For the purpose of this answer, I will assume you meant:

> If I haven't *davened* yet, am I still permitted to *daven*?

One version in the *Tur* ([OC 89](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x203)) is understood by the *Taz* ([OC 89:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x455)), and *Shulchan Aruch HaRav*<sup>1</sup> ([OC 89:2](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/8/89/2/index.htm)) rules that way as well, that if one hasn't *davened* within the first four hours of the day, he may still *daven* "*l'chatchila*" until midday.

The *Derech Chaim* ([28:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=31811#p=24&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=)) writes this as well.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to the [footnotes](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/8/89/2/index.htm#_ftn_5604) there, the *Bach* also holds that way, but I didn't notice it when I skimmed through it.

Comment: “If I haven’t *davened* yet, am I still permitted to *daven*?” That sounds like bediavad to me. I would have thought that l’chatchila meant that you can deliberately choose (without any compelling reason) to not daven earlier.

Comment: Does anyone disagree with the claim you've defended? The negation is something like: if you haven't davened by 4 hours just don't bother.