# Keeping Shabbos during the week?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, hashkafah-philosophy

Is there any value to or halachic discussion about keeping the laws of shabbos during the week?

Were there ever Rebbes or great people who did this on any level? (Excluding those who do it as part of Tosefes Shabbos, like the Amshinover Rebbe)

I'm referring to someone who, say, decides to "keep" shabbos for 6 hours on Tuesday.

Is this discouraged or prohibited?

Or might there be value to this?

Please provide sources.

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59137/27180

Comment: I keep shabbos for 6-8 hours a night

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89173/759

Comment: There are anecdotes about great people who would say to themselves "this is prohibited on Shabbat" every time they did something during the week that was forbidden on Shabbat. I no longer remember the details.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate @DoubleAA

Comment: Would Shabbat be a special time if you observed it every day?  The joy of life is in changes, not monotony.

Comment: @KirkBellard I don't believe this is a duplicate. Even if there is no obligation to work during the week, that does not mean there is value to cessation. I think that's a clear and significant distinction.